# If values from output are the same merge them together

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, merge

I feel that I'm getting close, but I'm not totally sure how to merge if the output of an `array_search` contains the same value in the output. FYI - I'm using WordPress to query this data.

Here's what I have so far:

*PHP:*

```
      <?php
      global $wpdb,$post;
      $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT $wpdb->posts.* FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'clients'");
      foreach ($result as $post):
        setup_postdata($post);
        $terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, array( 'state', 'product_type' ));
        $result = array_search('state', array_column($terms, 'taxonomy', 'name'));
        $term = $terms[0];
        ?>
        <?php if ($term -> taxonomy === 'state' && !empty($term)) : ?>
        <p><?php echo $terms[1]->name; ?>, <?php echo $terms[0]->name; ?></p>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php endforeach;?>
      <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Which will output:

```
Shirts, Alabama
Shirts, Colorado
Jeans, Colorado
Jeans, Iowa
Socks, Maine
```

But I want to group `Jeans` and `Shirts` together to output this:

```
Shirts, Alabama, Colorado
Jeans, Colorado, Iowa
Socks, Maine
```

This should also set it up so that if there is another item, like `Sweaters` for example it will group those items together as well.

I'm also not sure if I'm writing this "correctly" either, so I'm open to suggestions as well.

Comment: See array_unique() -> http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-unique.php

Comment: Are you displaying the comma separated data like that on the screen? or is this just how you are expressing your desired output for this question?  I mean, you could use `GROUP BY` AND `GROUP CONCAT()` to stitch this all together in the query, but I'm not sure how you are implementing your task.

Comment: Well, eventually, I'll have it output to something different, so I'm just displaying this for example and testing sake. I've looked into modifying my query, but the problem is that WordPress doesn't store the taxonomy data within the post table. I've tried to mess with doing some joins with the other tables that have a relation to the post and the taxonomies, but it never yielded the result I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can collect your data first, and print it in a separate loop. This makes grouping easier. In your example: Replace this line:

```
 <p><?php echo $terms[1]->name; ?>, <?php echo $terms[0]->name; ?></p>
```

with

```
<?php $my_output[$terms[1]->name][] = $terms[0]->name; ?>
```

to collect the data in a multidimensional array. And at the very end put:

```
<?php foreach($my_output as $key => $values): ?>
  <p><?php echo $key; ?>, <?php echo implode(',', $values); ?></p>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

to print all of it. Check the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) for the implode function I used. For best practices you should initialize `$my_output = array()` somewhere at the beginning (before the first foreach).

Comment: Oh wow. So I updated that and looks like it grouped it, but also looks like it's repeating some other items too:

`Shirts, Alabama`

`Shirts, Alabama,Colorado`

`Shirts, Alabama,Colorado`

`Jeans, Colorado`

`Shirts, Alabama,Colorado`

`Jeans, Colorado,Iowa`

`Shirts, Alabama,Colorado`

`Jeans, Colorado,Iowa`

`Socks, Maine`

Not sure if I messed something up or what.

Comment: That looks like you put my three lines of code inside your foreach loop. You need to put them after your loop; or after `<?php wp_reset_postdata();` ?>.

Comment: DAP! Ok yeah...looks like it outputting correctly. Thanks! I'm gonna test this out a bit more, but I _think_ this is it!